# How should I interpret the conditional expectation and how to define its expression associated to each case (if it is possible)?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, conditional-expectation

So I am studying the Rick Durrett book on probability theory and I am struggling to understand the notion of conditional expectation. Precisely speaking, let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})$ be a probability space and $X:(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\textbf{P})\to(\textbf{R},\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}))$ be a random variable. Given a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}'\subseteq\mathcal{F}$, we define the conditional expectation $\textbf{E}(X\mid\mathcal{F}')$ as the (almost surely) unique random variable $Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{F}',\textbf{P})\to(\textbf{R},\mathcal{B}(\textbf{R}))$ such that $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}'$-measurable and $\textbf{E}(X1_{A}) = \textbf{E}(Y1_{A})$ for every $A\in\mathcal{F}'$.

I have understood so far (hopefully correctly) that $\sigma$-algebra represents the information we have at hand about the random phenomena we are interested in. For example, given the sample space $\Omega = \{1,2,3\}$ whose associated $\sigma$-algebra can be explicitly written as $\mathcal{F} = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Moreover, we shall define the random variable $X:\Omega\to\textbf{R}$ as the identity $X(\omega) = \omega$.

If we consider the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}' = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}\subset\mathcal{F}$, we are giving the information that either the event $\{1\}$ occur or $\{2,3\}$ occur (please let me know if I am incorrect). To each possible case is associated the corresponding expected value. More precisely, if we assume that $\textbf{P}$ has uniform distribution and set that $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$, one gets that:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\textbf{E}(X1_{A}) = \dfrac{p\times 1}{p} = 1\\\\
\textbf{E}(X1_{B}) = \dfrac{p\times 2 + p\times 3}{2\times p} = 2.5 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Is it possible to state that?

If that is the case, we are allowed to set that $\textbf{P}(Y = 1) = 1/3$ and $\textbf{P}(Y = 2.5) = 2/3$?

If that is the case, how do we define the random variable $Y$?

Can we set $Y(1) = 1$ and $Y(2) = Y(3) = 2.5$?

In the case that I have proceeded correctly so far, I would like to know how do we determine the conditional expectation in the general case (if there is an unique possible way to do so).

Hopefully I have properly asked my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we consider the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}' = \{\varnothing,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}\subset\mathcal{F}$, we are giving the information that either the event $\{1\}$ occur or $\{2,3\}$ occur (please let me know if I am incorrect). To each possible case is associated the corresponding expected value. More precisely, if we assume that $\textbf{P}$ has uniform distribution and set that $A = \{1\}$ and $B = \{2,3\}$, one gets that:
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{cases}
> \textbf{E}(X1_{A}) = \dfrac{p\times 1}{p} = 1\\\\
> \textbf{E}(X1_{B}) = \dfrac{p\times 2 + p\times 3}{2\times p} = 2.5 
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}
>
> Is it possible to state that?

You don't have these computations quite right: note that the random variable $X 1_A$ maps $1 \in \Omega$ to $1$ and maps $2$ and $3$ to $0$. Hence, $\mathbb E[X 1_A] = 1 \cdot \frac 1 3 + 0 \cdot \frac 2 3 = \frac 1 3$. Similarly, $\mathbb E[X 1_B] = \frac 5 3$.

I suspect that you were thinking about the conditional expectations, i.e. $\mathbb E[X \mid A] := \mathbb E[X 1_A] / \mathbb P(A)$, which would indeed be $1$; similarly, $\mathbb E[X \mid B] = \frac{5/3}{2/3} = \frac 5 2$. (This foreshadows what's coming next.)

> If that is the case, we are allowed to set that $\textbf{P}(Y = 1) = 1/3$ and $\textbf{P}(Y = 2.5) = 2/3$?
>
> If that is the case, how do we define the random variable $Y$?
>
> Can we set $Y(1) = 1$ and $Y(2) = Y(3) = 2.5$?

Yes, this definition of $Y$ is exactly right; $Y$ is a random variable that maps $1$ to $1$ and maps $2$ and $3$ to $2.5$. Notice that this matches the "classical" definition of conditional expectation that I used above.

> In the case that I have proceeded correctly so far, I would like to know how do we determine the conditional expectation in the general case (if there is an unique possible way to do so).

In the general case, your task is (as always) to find a function that satisfies the definition of conditional expectation. That is: you need to find a random variable $Y$ that is $\mathcal F'$-measurable, and for any $S \in \mathcal F'$, it integrates to the correct value (i.e. $\int_S X \, \textrm d \mathbb P = \int_S Y \, \textrm d \mathbb P$). Conditional expectations are unique, so once you've found a function that behaves in this way, you're done.